# Sort a Lucene Faceted Search

Tags: java, sorting, lucene, faceted-search

I am using a pure Lucene 4.2.0 Faceted Search using the lucene-facet module.

I got it to work, but how can I change the sort behavior for the searcher? I use the following seacrh method of the searcher, but it doesn't take a Sort parameter.

```
FacetsCollector facetsCollector = FacetsCollector.create(facetSearchParams, indexReader, taxoIndexReader);
searcher.search(query, MultiCollector.wrap(facetsCollector));
List<FacetResult> res = facetsCollector.getFacetResults();
```

I get results with most matches on top. But is it possible to sort it alphabetically instead without sorting it in pre java?

Thanks a lot!
-Danny

Comment: I found out that you're able to sort the requested results using   `facetRequest.setSortOrder(FacetRequest.SortOrder.DESCENDING);`  But I am using `PER_NODE_IN_TREE` as result mode and my facet results are displayed always the same way.